# Annotation color only shows when text outside of Google Bar Chart

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-visualization

I have a google [bar chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart) and I am setting the font size and the color, however the color only applies when the text is outside of the bar.  How do I force the color to apply?

```
 annotations: {
        textStyle: {
          fontSize: 18,
          color:'#000000'
        }
      }
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

turn off `annotations.highContrast`

from the documentation...

> **annotations.highContrast** lets you override Google Charts choice of the annotation color.
>   By default, **annotations.highContrast** is true, which causes Charts to select an annotation color with good contrast: light colors on dark backgrounds, and dark on light.
>   If you set **annotations.highContrast** to false and don't specify your own annotation color, Google Charts will use the default series color for the annotation:

see following example, note the use of `textStyle.auraColor`

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div')).draw(
      google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Element', 'Density', { role: 'annotation' } ],
        ['Copper', 8.94, 'Cu' ],
        ['Silver', 10.49, 'Ag' ],
        ['Gold', 19.30, 'Au' ],
        ['Platinum', 21.45, 'Pt' ]
      ]),
      {
        annotations: {
          highContrast: false,
          textStyle: {
            auraColor: 'lime',
            color: '#000000',
            fontSize: 18
          }
        },
        colors: ['lime']
      }
    );
  },
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

another option might be `annotations.alwaysOutside`

Comment: Do you happen to know why the annotation text is aligning odd as well?

Comment: i'm thinking the chart is not taking `fontSize` into consideration. `annotations.alwaysOutside` _might_ help with that. otherwise, may need to set / adjust `height` and `width` options on the `chartArea`

Comment: I tried doing align left and that didn't seem to take. I want the text to be inside but left align

Comment: there isn't an option for `alignment` -- did you try `annotations.alwaysOutside: false` ? -- only other _possible_ option i can think of would be to modify the annotations directly using `JavaScript`, when the chart's `'ready'` event fires but not recommended

Comment: thank you very much for your help.  The answer is correct, but also exposes some inflexibility with Google Charts that I was hoping was not there.  Thank you again.