# i am working on google bar charts, i am stuck with adding colours to individual bars

Tags: charts, colors, annotations, google-visualization, bar-chart

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<body>

<h1>My Web Page</h1>

<div id="piechart"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
// Load google charts
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

// Draw the chart and set the chart values


var a = [['Work', 8], ['Eat', 2], ['TV', 4], ['Gym', 2], ['Sleep', 8], ['walk', 2], ['games', 2], ['chess', 2], ['drink', 4], ['dance', 6]];
a.sort(compareSecondColumn);

function compareSecondColumn(a, b) {
    if (a[1] === b[1]) {
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        return (a[1] > b[1]) ? -1 : 1;
    }
}



// Draw the chart and set the chart values
function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3],a[4]
        
    ]);
    // Optional; add a title and set the width and height of the chart
    var options = { 'title': 'the title', 'width': 550, 'height': 400 };
    // Display the chart inside the <div> element with id="piechart"
    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

[image: current output]

1. i am using bar chart, it only display default blue color.
2. i have used an array which removes the column which doesnot have data(like 0)
3. like sorting the data
4. i want to display individual color for each column
5. like red, green any different colors for each bar
6. i like to add annotations also
7. thanks in advance

Comment: check this answer for color --> [cannot Change Individual Bar Color](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36452554/5090771) -- and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37138250/5090771) for annotations

Comment: i tried by adding  ['Task', 'Hours per Day',{ role: "style" } and{ role: 'annotation' }  ]a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3],a[4]

Comment: then also it is showing blue

Comment: var a = [['Work', 8,"#b87333",8], ['Eat', 2,"#b87333",2], ['TV', 4,"#b87333",4]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the column headings and values posted in the above comments seem to work fine here...

the only changes made...

1. add `type` property to style and annotation roles.
2. added different colors for style role.

see following working snippet...

```js
var a = [['Work', 8, "#E53935", 8], ['Eat', 2, "#1E88E5", 2], ['TV', 4, "#43A047", 4]];
a.sort(compareSecondColumn);

function compareSecondColumn(a, b) {
  if (a[1] === b[1]) {
    return 0;
  }
  else {
    return (a[1] > b[1]) ? -1 : 1;
  }
}

google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Task', 'Hours per Day', {role: 'style', type: 'string'}, {role: 'annotation', type: 'number'}],a[0],a[1],a[2]
  ]);

  var options = {
    title: 'the title',
    width: 550,
    height: 400,
    legend: 'none'
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="piechart"></div>
```